# EF .Net core 2.0 - Using OwnOne with HasDefaultValueSql for Id (type: Guid)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have 2 Entities. **Order** and **Address** (as Value Object in DDD).
I want Id Property of **Order** to be generated by Guid.NewGuid(). I've configured as the following

```
class OrderEntityTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Order>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Order> orderConfiguration)
    {
        orderConfiguration.ToTable("orders", OrderingContext.DEFAULT_SCHEMA);

        orderConfiguration.HasKey(o => o.Id);

        orderConfiguration.Ignore(b => b.DomainEvents);

        orderConfiguration.Property(b => b.Id).HasDefaultValueSql<Guid>("(newid())");

        //Address value object persisted as owned entity type supported since EF Core 2.0
        orderConfiguration.OwnsOne(o => o.Address);

    }
}
```

But, when using command "**dotnet ef migrations add InitialDatabase**" for creating migration, which throw error " ***'Order.Id' and 'Order.Address#Address.OrderId' are both mapped to column 'Id' in  'ordering.orders' but are configured to use different default values ('(newid())' and '').***"

Please, help me. I'm new in .net Core2, EF core as well. Thank you.

Comment: It's a bug. See [Owned types and key default values unintuitive to configure #10308](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/10308)

Comment: That's helpful for me, thanks a lot!